# Como obtener archivos JSON de la API de Telegram con javascript del lado cliente, ejemplo en Chrome, y separar sus componentes para luego procesarlos?

Tags: javascript, json, webapi, telegram-bot, xmlhttprequest

**¿Es posible controlar un bot de Telegram  con javascript?**
Intento realizar un `XMLHttpRequest()` desde
Chrome, para obtener un archivo .json desde
la API de Telegram. Supongo que no puede ser
por el método `GET`, pues la url contiene datos
sensibles (Token), pero el objetivo es obtener, no
enviar, un JSON. No logro obtener nada en la
respuesta, o el código está muy mal, necesito que
funcione desde el lado cliente, para enviar un
mensaje de prueba al bot:

```
<div id="objeto"></div>
<div id="error"></div>

<script>
var objeto = document.getElementById('objeto');
var error = document.getElementById('error');

//Visualizar resultados
function display(obj, sp) {
 for (n in obj) {
  if (typeof obj[n] == 'object') {
   display(obj[n], n + ".");
  }else{
   objeto.innerHTML+= "<span>" + sp + n + ": " + obj[n] + "</span><br />";
  }
 }
}

//Preparación de la solicitud
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (req.readyState === 4)
    if  (req.status == "200") {

        req.responseType = 'json';
        var obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        display(obj,""); //Llamada mostrar resultados

    } else {
            error.innerText = "Error, estado de solicitud:  " + req.status + ".";
        }
};

req.open('POST', 'https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getUpdates', true);
req.send(null); //null, o es necesario enviar getUpdates?
</script>
```

Los elementos que se obtendrían en este caso son:
**JSON**

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": [
    {
        "update_id": 000000000,
        "message": {
            "message_id": 2,
            "from": {
                "id": 000000000,
                "is_bot": false,
                "first_name": " ",
                "last_name": " ",
                "username": " ",
                "language_code": "es"
            },
            "chat": {
                "id": 000000000,
                "first_name": " ",
                "last_name": " ",
                "username": " ",
                "type": " "
            },
            "date": 0000000000,
            "text": "Hola"
        }
    }]
}
```

Entonces la cuestión sería:

A. Como organizar el código javascript
correctamente para que obtenga datos de
esa API?, y

B. Es correcta esa forma de separar los
componentes obtenidos?
Obviamente se necesita un servidor
pero quiero realizar pruebas del lado cliente,
específicamente en Chrome para android.
Que me recomiendas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El request `getUpdates` de Telegram es GET, y puede ser llamado con JavaScript desde el cliente, este es un ejemplo con `fetch` que es mas corto que `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
fetch('https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getUpdates')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => display(data,""));
```

Respecto de como mostrarlo, no veo que nada mal en tu función `display()`.

Comment: Realmente deceo lograrlo, gracias @Emeeus. Probaré tu código, hermano. Lo digo no porque dude de usted, sino porque he buscado y buscado, y nada. Incluso en MDN, que encontré uno y con mucha ilusión lo probé hoy desde la madrugada, y todo el día realizando pruebas. Terminé pensando que algo anda mal con mi móvil, porque como es posible que no funcione algo que se comparte en esa web? No es lógico para mí! Te dejaré otro comentario para que veas el "bosquejo" que quedó del código,  jaja. Claro, no es el original ya, todo un rompecabezas dejé. Mira...

Comment: var requestURL = './getUpdates.json';
//var requestURL = 'https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/getUpdates';
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', requestURL);
req.responseType = 'json'
req.send();
req.onreadystatechange = estado;
function estado()
{
   var myfile = req.response;

   //if (req.readyState === 4)
   if  (req.status == 0) { //200 ok

//var obj = JSON.parse(myfile);
display(obje,"");
lert(myfile); //null  ~( :-{(

            //opciones(obje);
        } else {
            error.innerText = "Error, estado de solicitud:  " + req.status + ".";
        }
}

Comment: Quizá el token no es correcto, ese código con mí token ha funcionado, fíjate que en la última parte utilice la función que has definido, no te olvides de incluirla.

Comment: Funcionó PERFECTOOOO! Muchísimas gracias @Emeeus. Lo que aún no comprendo es por qué el `XMLHttpRequest` no me funcionó, pero ya no lo necesito, gracias a tu ayuda y tiempo. Gracias gracias gracias....

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al apoyo de @Emeeus, éste es
el código que logré y es funcional: √

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<title>Bosquejo</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="objeto" style="font-size: 12px"></div>
<div id="error"></div>

<script>
var objeto = document.getElementById('objeto');
var error = document.getElementById('error'); //No implementado aún

function display(obj, sp) {
 for (n in obj) {
  if (typeof obj[n] == 'object') {
   display(obj[n], n + ".");
  }else{

   objeto.innerHTML+= "<span>" + sp + n + ": " + obj[n] + "</span><br />";
  }
 }
}

//var requestURL = './getUpdates.json'; //Para archivos locales

//Por @Emeeus
fetch('https://api.telegram.org/botELTOKENAQUÍ/getUpdates')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => display(data,""));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Y ahora, a realizar nuevas funciones y pruebas!